# NHibernate like model versioning for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In NHibernate it's possible to work with versions using the same table and just add a version number column to that table [see here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/14/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency.aspx). For severe performance reasons I'd like that logic to be contained in the same table not in a collection table. Is there anything like that for Rails or do I need to roll our own?

I have looked at all the options available like audited, vestal_versions, paper_trail and must say I am disappointed in all of them. They are not only cumbersome to use the right way but also performance bottlenecks. To restore a version in paper_trail I have to do 3 queries to the database to fetch the data to restore and then another query to update.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [Optimistic Locking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#optimistic-locking)?

Comment: Partly but I want append only versioning as well http://ayende.com/blog/4196/append-only-models-with-nhibernate